# CMake basic usage

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build my library with CMake. I'm working on CMakeLists.txt .

I want to be able to do the following:

I have a directories called

```
include
src
```

Then inside of these there is
Agui folder.
And in that folder are the sub folders of the library.

So far from what I've gathered:

I'll need to do:

```
set(AGUI_SOURCES
src/Agui/Rectangle.cpp
src/Agui/xxx.cpp (and so on)
)
```

Then I think need to do:

```
include_directories(./include)
```

And then I'm not quite sure.

I know that add_library will be involved but I'm not sure how.

The thing is, I want to create 2 options: DLL, or static.

If it is DLL, then AGUI_BUILD_DLL must be defined.

So based on this information:

1. Am I on the right track?
2. How do I create the options
3. What do I put in add_library
4. How do I add the preprocessor AGUI_BUILD_DLL if the user wants the DLL version?

If any or all of these could be answered I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the [CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) which covers adding executables, libraries, system introspection etc. The cmake command also self documents, so on the command line entering,

```
cmake --help-command add_library
```

would give you the documentation for the add_library command. You could use the --help-commands to get a full listing of all CMake command documentation. So you can use the option command to add an option for building shared or static, and use the add_definitions command to add a preprocessor definition.

For example,

```
option(BUILD_SHARED "Build shared libraries" OFF)
if(BUILD_SHARED)
  add_definitions(-DAGUI_BUILD_DLL)
  add_library(agui SHARED ${AGUI_SOURCES})
else()
  add_library(agui STATIC ${AGUI_SOURCES})
endif()
```

You should note targetName_EXPORTS will be defined when building the library, and so can be used in the declspec logic. This is done by CMake, and is also useful when using visibility support in GCC on Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe , do not know :)
2. OPTION(AGUI_BUILD_DLL "Build agui DLL" OFF)
   somewhere near the start of CMakeLists.txt. You may want to use ON instead of OFF - depends on whether you want DLL build to de default.

3,4.

```
if(AGUI_BUILD_DLL)
  add_library(agui SHARED ${AGUI_SOURCES})
  set_target_properties(agui PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL "AGUI_BUILD_DLL")
else()
  add_library(agui STATIC ${AGUI_SOURCES})
endif()
```